# Google Sheets - QUERY() - Sums of rows

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to use `QUERY()` to get the sums of rows into cells?

For example, I have

```
a b c d
1 2 3 2
3 4 2 6
4 6 3 3
```

and I want to use `QUERY()` to get:

```
8
15
16
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will sum the numerical values in the rows. It does not get the 'a':

```
=transpose(query(transpose(QUERY(A:D,"select * offset 1",0)),"select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3) label sum(Col1)'', sum(Col2)'',sum(Col3)''"))
```

Returns:

8

15

16

Here is my test spreadsheet:

```
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1At60xluiG_JvNh9onPgxGt9TeWMJ8l00o2pwUxWbnBM/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: AVG_SUM_ONLY_NUMERIC